# Raspbian - Transmission torrents don't start after rebooting

Tags: bash, cron, raspbian, torrent, transmission

I wrote a bash file and put in cron to start my torrents (on web interface) automatically after rebooting the system, but nothing happens.

**The crontab -e**

```
@reboot bash /home/pi/torrent.sh >> /home/pi/torrent.log 2>&1
```

**torrent.sh**

```
echo
date
sudo service transmission-daemon start
sleep 10
sudo transmission-remote -t all -s
sleep 1
```

The `torrent.sh` has got all permissions.

P.S.: If I run the script from terminal my torrents start normally.

Hope you can help!

Comment: Try providing full path for transmission-daemon in the shell script.

Comment: It doesn't help :(